# Error while installing vlc player

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I am trying to install the VLC on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, while installing I got an error like below, please help me.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

try these steps :

```
  sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then install synaptic:

```
  sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Use aptitude instead of apt-get:

```
  sudo aptitude install vlc
```

if you don't have aptitude on your machine yet, get it with:

```
  sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: Hi George James, Thank you very much, Its working.

Comment: no worries, you're welcome.

Comment: It's usually considered more proper if you edit your existing answers instead of adding tons more.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of troubleshooting may be to use aptitude rather than apt-get to try to install your package:

Use aptitude instead of apt-get:

```
sudo aptitude install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Installation of VLC using Synaptic Package Manager :**

[image]

Select vlc and click on “Mark for Installation” and then click on Apply.